# Usage of free() for Structure members

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, structure

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>
struct sample
{
   int a;
   char *String;
};

void func1(struct sample *par)
{

   par->String = (char *) malloc( 10 * sizeof(char));
   par->a = 3044;
   par->String = "xyz12345";
}

main()
{
   struct sample *x;
   x = (struct sample *) malloc(sizeof(struct sample));
   func1(x);
   printf("values = %d --- %s\n", x->a,x->String);
   free(x->String);     
   free(x);   
   return 0;
}
```

Here I want to free the memory allocated to x->String. free(x->String) outputs segmentation fault. Can anyone please tell me how can i free the memory allocated to x->String?

Comment: Your problem isn't the `free` itself, it the assignment `par->String = "foo";` in `func1`. It's the exact same issue as the linked question, and the accepted answer has the explanation and fix.

Comment: Ok i got the problem.Thanks Mat.